# zero mq pub/sub with multipart not working

Tags: python, publish-subscribe, zeromq

Here's my script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import traceback
import sys
import zmq
from time import sleep

print "Creating the zmq.Context"
context = zmq.Context()

print "Binding the publisher to the local socket at port 5557"
sender = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
sender.bind("tcp://*:5557")

print "Binding the subscriber to the local socket at port 5557"
receiver = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
receiver.connect("tcp://*:5557")

print "Setting the subscriber option to get only those originating from \"B\""
receiver.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "B")

print "Waiting a second for the socket to be created."
sleep(1)

print "Sending messages"
for i in range(1,10):
    msg = "msg %d" % (i)
    env = None
    if i % 2 == 0:
        env = ["B", msg]
    else:
        env = ["A", msg]
    print "Sending Message:  ", env
    sender.send_multipart(env)

print "Closing the sender."
sender.close()

failed_attempts = 0
while failed_attempts < 3:
    try:
        print str(receiver.recv_multipart(zmq.NOBLOCK))
    except:
        print traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info())
        failed_attempts += 1 

print "Closing the receiver."
receiver.close()

print "Terminating the context."
context.term()

"""
Output:

Creating the zmq.Context
Binding the publisher to the local socket at port 5557
Binding the subscriber to the local socket at port 5557
Setting the subscriber option to get only those originating from "B"
Waiting a second for the socket to be created.
Sending messages
Sending Message:   ['A', 'msg 1']
Sending Message:   ['B', 'msg 2']
Sending Message:   ['A', 'msg 3']
Sending Message:   ['B', 'msg 4']
Sending Message:   ['A', 'msg 5']
Sending Message:   ['B', 'msg 6']
Sending Message:   ['A', 'msg 7']
Sending Message:   ['B', 'msg 8']
Sending Message:   ['A', 'msg 9']
Closing the sender.
['B', 'msg 2']
['B', 'msg 4']
['B', 'msg 6']
['B', 'msg 8']
['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "./test.py", line 43, in \n    print str(receiver.recv_multipart(zmq.NOBLOCK))\n', '  File "socket.pyx", line 611, in zmq.core.socket.Socket.recv_multipart (zmq/core/socket.c:5181)\n', '  File "socket.pyx", line 514, in zmq.core.socket.Socket.recv (zmq/core/socket.c:4811)\n', '  File "socket.pyx", line 548, in zmq.core.socket.Socket.recv (zmq/core/socket.c:4673)\n', '  File "socket.pyx", line 99, in zmq.core.socket._recv_copy (zmq/core/socket.c:1344)\n', 'ZMQError: Resource temporarily unavailable\n']
['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "./test.py", line 43, in \n    print str(receiver.recv_multipart(zmq.NOBLOCK))\n', '  File "socket.pyx", line 611, in zmq.core.socket.Socket.recv_multipart (zmq/core/socket.c:5181)\n', '  File "socket.pyx", line 514, in zmq.core.socket.Socket.recv (zmq/core/socket.c:4811)\n', '  File "socket.pyx", line 548, in zmq.core.socket.Socket.recv (zmq/core/socket.c:4673)\n', '  File "socket.pyx", line 99, in zmq.core.socket._recv_copy (zmq/core/socket.c:1344)\n', 'ZMQError: Resource temporarily unavailable\n']
['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "./test.py", line 43, in \n    print str(receiver.recv_multipart(zmq.NOBLOCK))\n', '  File "socket.pyx", line 611, in zmq.core.socket.Socket.recv_multipart (zmq/core/socket.c:5181)\n', '  File "socket.pyx", line 514, in zmq.core.socket.Socket.recv (zmq/core/socket.c:4811)\n', '  File "socket.pyx", line 548, in zmq.core.socket.Socket.recv (zmq/core/socket.c:4673)\n', '  File "socket.pyx", line 99, in zmq.core.socket._recv_copy (zmq/core/socket.c:1344)\n', 'ZMQError: Resource temporarily unavailable\n']
Closing the receiver.
Terminating the context.
"""
```

And, the question is... why doesn't this code work?

[EDIT]  After getting a super quick response on the zeromq mailing list, I've updated the code above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Credit:  Chuck Remes

> You may need a "sleep" between the socket creation steps (bind, connect, setsockopt) and the actual transmission of the messages. The bind & connect operations are asynchronous, so they may not complete by the time you get to the logic that sends all of the messages. In that case, any messages sent through the PUB socket will be *dropped* since a zmq_bind() operation does not create a queue until another socket has successfully connected to it.
>
> As a side note, you don't need to create 2 contexts in this example. Both sockets can be created within the same context. It doesn't hurt, but it also isn't necessary.

Credit:  Pieter

> There is a "problem solver" at the end of Ch1 that explains this.
>
> Some socket types (ROUTER and PUB) will silently drop messages for
>   which they have no recipients. Connecting is, as Chuck said,
>   asynchronous and takes approx 100msec. If you start two threads, bind
>   one side, connect the other, and then start immediately to send data
>   over such a socket type, you'll lose the first 100msec of data
>   (approximately).
>
> Doing a sleep is a brutal "prove that it works" option. Realistically
>   you'd synchronize in some way, or (more typically) expect message loss
>   as part of normal startup (i.e. see the published data as a pure
>   broadcast with no definite start or end).
>
> See weather update example, syncpub and syncsub for details.

Answer (score 2):

Necro-posting, but for those interested in a solution other than sleeping, there are monitors.

You can set a monitor callback and get called on ZMQ_EVENT_CONNECTED events.

See details and example at http://api.zeromq.org/3-3:zmq-ctx-set-monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can publish a continuous stream of *hello* messages initially and let subscriber respond with an acknowledgment once a message is consumed. You may then terminate sending probe messages upon receiving the ack and start sending the actual messages ([Documentation](https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter2/#Node-Coordination)).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).